How to fix opecv building error on windows for gocv
I'm trying to prepare gocv for work with it. I followed their windows tutorial to install and build opencv.
But while running win_build_opencv.cmd building fails on mingw32-make install step with these errors:
[  3%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/parallel.cpp.obj
C:\opencv\opencv-4.9.0\modules\core\src\parallel.cpp: In function 'int cv::getThreadNum()':
C:\opencv\opencv-4.9.0\modules\core\src\parallel.cpp:804:25: error: invalid cast from type 'pthread_t' {aka 'ptw32_handle_t'} to type 'void*'
  804 |     return (int)(size_t)(void*)pthread_self(); // no zero-based indexing
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir\build.make:1002: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/parallel.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/parallel.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:3619: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:164: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2

C:\opencv\opencv-4.9.0\modules\core\src\parallel_impl.cpp: In constructor 'cv::WorkerThread::       WorkerThreadBuilding CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/utils/samples.cpp.obj
(cv::ThreadPool&, unsigned int)':
C:\opencv\opencv-4.9.0\modules\core\src\parallel_impl.cpp:218:9: error: no matching function for call to 'ptw32_handle_t::ptw32_handle_t(int)'
  218 |         posix_thread(0),
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\opencv\opencv-4.9.0\modules\core\src\parallel_impl.cpp:10[ 24%] :Building CXX object mo
C:/Program Files/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/pthread.h:584:3: note: candidate: 'ptw32_handle_t::ptw32_handle_t()'
  584 | } ptw32_handle_t;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

What should I do to fix this?
